# Internet Archive Dump of StackExchange Data

Tags: discussion, data-dump

The new dump of StackExchange data that has been posted on Internet Archive, does it contain previous snapshots of the data or does it just contain the snapshot at Jan 20th,2014. If it does not contain the previous snapshots (that were hosted on clearbits), does SO plan to put them on Internet Archive?

Thanks for all the help !

Comment: There are some older (less frequent) ones available from [Clearbits](http://cache.preserve.io/2z8x0ivw/index.html).